# How to display floating point number from table show as digit format

Tags: php, floating-point

In my table i have the record value 0.0000009 like this since i run my program i got result like this 9.0E-7. But i need to display 0.0000009 this format.

```
<?php echo $a=0.0000009; ?>
```

Kindly guide me

Comment: http://in3.php.net/number_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formatting print, %f means that you bind float value, "1" symbols before point, "8" after point:

```
echo sprintf('%1.8f', 0.00000009);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.